# How to use whole list function argument in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I can understand most of the `[H|T]` examples I read in the docs. I usually means that I want to use either the `H` or the `T` part of the list. What if I want to use the whole list instead. Sample code:

```
-module(module_variable).
-export([main/0, list_suffix/1]).

variable() -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

list_suffix([_H|T]) ->
        lists:suffix(variable, T).

main() ->
        io:fwrite("~p~n", [list_suffix([4, 5])]).
```

The error I get is:

```
6> module_variable:list_suffix([1,[4, 5]]).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  length/1
        called as length(variable)
     in call from lists:suffix/2 (lists.erl, line 205)
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: You just write `L`

Comment: one more thing - in your code `variable` is an atom not call of function `variable/0`

Comment: If I do that I get errors like this: ```8> module_variable:list_suffix([1,[4, 5]]).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  length/1
        called as length(variable)
     in call from lists:suffix/2 (lists.erl, line 205)```

Comment: Yeah the `variable` was the problem, it should have been `variable()`

Comment: so now your problem solved?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much

Comment: If for some reason erlang didn't allow you to match whole lists, you could always construct the whole list in the body of a function from the H and T variables.  How would you do that? `[H|T]`

Comment: found the answer? post it, and accept it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple values from the front of the list. You cannot skip an arbitrary number of values in the middle. Since in your code you don't know how many elements from the head you want to match ahead of time, pattern matching can't do this for you.

Some examples:

Setup:

```
1> A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Matches first 2 elements of list

```
2> [1, 2 | _ ] = A.
[1,2,3,4,5]
% Can pattern match to extract values
3> [B, C | _ ] = A.    
[1,2,3,4,5]
4> B.
1
5> C.
2
```

Can match some constant values and also assign

```
6> [1, 2, D | _ ] = A.
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Can match whole list

```
7> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] = A. 
[1,2,3,4,5]
% Can't skip over elements in the middle
8> [1, 2| [4, 5]] = A. 
** exception error: no match of right hand side value [1,2,3,4,5]
% This works, though not useful most of the time:
9> [1, 2, 3 | [4, 5]] = A.
[1,2,3,4,5]
% Can assign every element
10> [B, C, D, E, F] = A.
[1,2,3,4,5]
11> E.
4
12> F.
5
% If you don't use a pipe, the length has to match exactly
13> [B, C, D, E] = A.   
** exception error: no match of right hand side value [1,2,3,4,5]
```